# How can I only compare dd/mm against dd/mm/yyyy in Google sheets?

Tags: python, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

Today I have a bit more of a complicated question:

I have a Google sheet that has the has real dates (`dd/mm/yyyy`) in one column.

While checking, I want to check it against the following:

```py
date_format = datetime.today().strftime('%d/%m')
```

Which would only check `dd/mm` as I am not interested in the year, but can't change it either.

Is Python/gspread able to take care of this? Is a comparison like this even possible?

While reading out the column, you can't subscript the 'Cell' of course.

I tried to use some regex I found:

```py
criteria_re = re.compile('(?<!\d)((((0?\d)|([12]\d)|(3[01]))/(((0?((1[02]?)|([3578]))))|(1[0-2])))|(((0?\d)|([12]\d))/(0?2))|(((0?\d)|([12]\d)|(30))/((0?[2469])|(11))))/((19)|(20))\d\d')
cell_list = worksheet.findall(criteria_re, in_column=1)

# This is returned: [<Cell R1C1 '21/08/2020'>, <Cell R2C1 '23/08/2020'>]
```

Which however only checks for real dates, but I only want to check if an entry matches the `dd/mm` of **today** by using the `date_format` above.

I also tried to remove the last `5` characters, but that converts the output into a `str` and I need it as an `int` to then check something like this:

```py
cell_list = worksheet.findall(date_format, in_column=1) # All values that match the date, only want to look for dd/mm though

for match in cell_list:

    values_list = worksheet.row_values(match.row) # Gets the row where the cell was found
```

*I other words: I still need to get the location of the cell as I can't just search for `dd/mm` if the format in the sheet is `dd/mm/yyyy`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the rows by searching `dd/mm` from the values of `dd/mm/yyyy`.
- You want to achieve this using gspreads for python.

In this case, how about the following sample script? In this sample script, from your question, I used the cell values as the string values.

#### Sample script:

```py
searchColumn = 1  # Please set the search column. In this case, it's the column "A".
search = "22/08" # Please set the search value.

criteria_re = re.compile("(?<!\d)((((0?\d)|([12]\d)|(3[01]))/(((0?((1[02]?)|([3578]))))|(1[0-2])))|(((0?\d)|([12]\d))/(0?2))|(((0?\d)|([12]\d)|(30))/((0?[2469])|(11))))/((19)|(20))\d\d") # This is from your script.
values = worksheet.get_all_values()
res = [r for r in values if criteria_re.search(r[searchColumn - 1]) and r[searchColumn - 1][:-5] == search]
print(res)
```

- When this script is run, the values are searched from the column "A". When the searched values are found, the row values are retrieved.

### Added:

When you want to retrieve the searched row number, how about the following sample script? In this case, the 1st-row number is `1`.

#### Sample script:

```py
searchColumn = 1  # Please set the search column. In this case, it's the column "A".
search = "22/08" # Please set the search value.

criteria_re = re.compile("(?<!\d)((((0?\d)|([12]\d)|(3[01]))/(((0?((1[02]?)|([3578]))))|(1[0-2])))|(((0?\d)|([12]\d))/(0?2))|(((0?\d)|([12]\d)|(30))/((0?[2469])|(11))))/((19)|(20))\d\d") # This is from your script.
values = worksheet.get_all_values()
res = [i + 1 for i, r in enumerate(values) if criteria_re.search(r[searchColumn - 1]) and r[searchColumn - 1][:-5] == search]
print(res)
```

Comment: This solution leads me into the right direction. It returns the whole row, though. I think this is not a huge problem, as I can just access the entries in the list that gets created. If you find a solution that narrows it down to just the col (including the position) that I can work with at the end (`worksheet.row_values(match.row)`), feel free to include it. This solution works totally fine though!

Comment: @R6Winner Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added one more sample script for retrieving the searched row number. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your reply, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give another solution. This all works fine for me now, thanks!